# Regex Javascript: Remove single charcaters in Text

Tags: javascript, regex

I imagine this question is very simple for experts, yet I can't figure this one out (not even reading through stackoverflow & google):

I want to remove all alphanumeric and umlaut (and double S) single characters (i.e. or if not possible, then surrounded by spaces). Here what I tried:

```
    var a = "text 0 1 2 3 a 4 text text";
    a = a.replace(/\b\s+[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜß]\s+\b/g, ' ')
    a = a.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ') + "\n" //remove double spaces
    alert(a)
```

What I get: `text 1 3 4 text text`
Expected output: `text text text`

see also: [Fiddle snippet](https://fiddle.jshell.net/zsrnvck0/6/)

edit: updated my try according to comments thanks @stanislav-Šolc

Comment: \s* means zero or more, that is way how you loose all numbers at text. Change \s* to any other multipler, to \s+ fo example, or you can use word boundary (anchor) \b[0-9]\b that will handle even single chars on the end of the line...

Comment: a.replace('\s{2,}',' ') and a.replace('\s\d\s',' ')

Comment: @prizm: does not give me the right output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A positive lookahead (?= ) could help here.

```js
var a = "text 0 ä 1 ë 2 i      text ";
a = a.replace(/ [a-zA-Z0-9äëïöÄËÜÏÖ](?= )/g, '');
a = a.replace(/  +/g, ' ');
alert(a);
```

The first regex will look for a space and a character, followed by a space.

So it will return :

```
text text
```

And if you want to be more thourough about removing single characters then this could be tried:

```
a = a.replace(/ [^ ](?= )/g, '');
```

But that could probable remove also stuff you want

Comment: reading up on lookaheads, thanks, / [^ ](?= )/g was exactly what I needed. I was looking into word boundaries etc... this is perfect thanks

Comment: I actually first should about using a wordboundairy \b.  But that doesn't seem to work well with the umluads.